# Find number of items in each ExtJs grid group

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to find property which gives me number of items in Each ExtJs grid group so that I can only collapse that group if there are more than one item. I tried at add watch on grdItems but couldn't get right property which displays correct value.

```
var view = Ext.getCmp('Grid').getView();
var groupFeature = view.getFeature('groupSummary');
grdItems = view.getEl().query('.x-grid-group-hd');

if (grdItems.length > 0)
{
    for (i = 0; i < grdItems.length; i++)
    {
    }
}
```

When I do this grdItems[i].children.length, it gives "1" for every group even if there are more than 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the store, use [`getGroups()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-getGroups):

> Returns a collection of readonly sub-collections of your store's
>   records with grouping applied. These sub-collections are maintained
>   internally by the collection.

For example:

```
var groups = grid.getStore().getGroups();

groups.each(function(group) {
    console.log(group.getGroupKey(), group.getCount());
});
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1469